# Default-expand-all doesn't work for q-tree? Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, nodes

I have to code a web application and the most important element is the q-tree. I'm already able to load and show data (passing an array called list), but I want that all nodes are expanded.

The vue.js examples of the official documentation show that you're be able to do this with the 'default-expand-all' attribute but this isn't working for me.

It only shows me the root node with an arrow, where I have to expand the children nodes manually.

```
    <q-tree
     :nodes="list"
     :selected.sync="selected"
     @update:selected="onSelectionChangedNode"
     node-key="NodeNr"
     label-key="NodeTxt"
     default-expand-all
    ></q-tree>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem as following:

I have added a ref attribute to the QTree DOM Element which makes it possible to access predefined methods of QTree API.

```
      <q-tree
        :nodes="list"
        :selected.sync="selected"
        @update:selected="onSelectionChangedNode"
        node-key="NodeNr"
        label-key="NodeTxt"
        **ref="nodes"**
      >
```

The function I have been using is expandAll().

```
updated() {
      this.$refs.nodes.expandAll();
}
```

The most important thing for me was, I had to find out which lifecycle hook was the right one for me. The update() hook was the one I was looking for.

> The reason:

> Called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and
> patched.

> The component’s DOM will have been updated when this hook is called, so you
> can perform DOM-dependent operations here.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a cue from the accepted answer, I realised that the dom has already been created with the tree component on first render.

In my use case, I want to update the Tree when data comes back from the server.
So, I had to force it to re-render with the `expanded` functionality using:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
              this.$refs.nodes.expandAll();
            })
```

The nextTick function will update the dom in the next window of execution, by which time the nodes will get expanded by calling the `expandAll` function.

And NB: For those confused by the astericks on the ref attribute or how to add it to the component, here goes:

```
<q-tree :nodes="list"
        :selected.sync="selected"
        @update:selected="onSelectionChangedNode"
        node-key="NodeNr"
        label-key="NodeTxt"
        ref="nodes"
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

The default-expand-all is only applied on the first rendering of that Component.
So if your Component renders when the nodes aren't assigned they wont expand if assigned afterwards.

https://v1.quasar-framework.org/vue-components/tree

You have to work with scoped slots and an expanded attribute if you dont have the nodes on first rendering.